# Fill up the grid with the letters 'P', 'U', and 'Z' in the following way

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Fill up the grid,

[image],

so that the letters '$P$', '$U$', and '$Z$' occur the same number of times both column-wise and row-wise, as well as diagonally for *all* diagonals with a number of cells that is a multiple of three (two examples are indicated above in color).

---

Comment: I assume that also includes the diagonals going the other direction?

Comment: No assumption: "all diagonals"

Comment: "*occur the same number of times both column-wise and row-wise*" - what does this mean? Every column and row has three P's, three U's, and three Z's?

Comment: @Randal'Thor, consider the column individually. This column must have the same number of each P, U, and Z. Example: PUZZUPUPZ This goes for rows also. All columns. All rows. All indicated diagonals. Does that help?

Answer (score 6):

This is akin to:

> [IMO 2016 question 2](https://www.imo-official.org/year_info.aspx?year=2016)

So the grid can only be filled if:

> The side length is a multiple of 9

And can be filled by tessellating the following tile in the normal fashion:

> ```
> PPPUUUZZZ
> UUUZZZPPP
> ZZZPPPUUU
> ```

Comment: Aww. It's not as interesing a puzzle as I'd hoped.

Comment: I upvoted your comment.